# Generate random number with rand() between negative and positive limits

Tags: php

How can I generate random integer with negative and positive brackets? Like from -552 to 2200?

Comment: Asking basic questions that can be answered just by reading the manual isn't encouraging either

Comment: @mark, i did read the manual. just thought from the manual the min number is 0 as i seldom use rand(). Now i know. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `$rand = rand(-552, 2200);` ?